# Mysql update query, setwise, incrementing date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have to update a column (called '`next-interaction`') in a table. The column contains date-time as values (ex: `'2011-07-12 18:30:00'` ).  I have 160 records after applying all my where clauses.

Now, I have to make sets of 15 records and update their `next-interaction` column with dates starting from '`2014-01-06 16:00:00`' (excluding weekend dates).

In the sense,

```
    first 15 records -> 2014-01-06 16:00:00  ( -> date-interaction column )
    next 15 records -> 2014-01-07 16:00:00
    next 15 records -> 2014-01-08 16:00:00
```

like wise, excluding saturdays and sundays dates to be incremented.

How can I do this? Can I do this with queries alone, or should i have to write a small `php`-script for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a **Cursor** to solve the problem. A Cursor allows you to go through all the records of a table sequentially.

- Declare and open a Cursor [(link)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html)

  - something like `DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT next-interaction FROM your_table;`
- Declare a "counter variable" i.e. "i" and a "date variable" i.e. "d"
- As long as the counter variable < 15 -> update the record
- If the counter variable >= 15, set it to 0 and increment your date variable by 1 day, something like `d = DATE_ADD(d ,INTERVAL 1 DAY)` and update the record
- With `DAYOFWEEK(d) = 6 or DAYOFWEEK(d) = 7` you can check, if your date is a weekend

If you have to execute the code regularly I would recommend declaring a **stored procedure** [(link)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

I haven't tested this.